# Automatically raise flag when using "Share feedback" option

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, first-questions, abandoned-questions

When reviewing, I'm using a lot of time the "Share feedback" choice.

I see a lot of questions that are:

- not updated
- not answered
- bad (need code/focus/...)
- few views

And with comments that ask for edits to make the question on-topic. The questions stay here, not removed, with 0 votes, no action, no attention and we can't answer it.

For example, I just open my "First Question" history, then go to a random page. Then I search all "Share feedback" reviews.

- [Showing different list on android TV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70030794/10952503)
- [Trying to add horizontal scroll to my page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70030830/10952503)
- [HTML coding for block elements containing data and information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70023918/10952503)<sup>1</sup>
- [Resolving the updating of AppWidget in launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69786753/10952503)
- [Enable debugging via USB and install via USB from xiaomi note 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69788670/10952503)<sup>1</sup> (-1 by me)
- [Cannot export .sql file from phpmyadmin in MACOS. SQL is not generating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69775978/10952503)
- [how to import excel file in ag-grid angular](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69770630/10952503) (this one receive a (bad) answer)

And I take only a few questions from 2 random pages (I didn't search a lot, it's easy to find them. Make the [test yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/history) :) ). A lot of them will stay forever somewhere without any way to answer. Also, we can't put them as duplicate because we don't know the issue.

So, I propose to automatically raise close flag to prevent those type of question.
(thanks @yivi for suggestion).

I'm mostly talking about *First Question* review, but I think it's the same for others.

<sup>1</sup>(this question received one downvote, so can be removed automatically a day)

Comment: Oh, the [Meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/10952503) is managing all mentionned questions. *(The Meta Effect seems to also be called "Zoe" xD)*

Comment: If you think the questions are poor quality or not useful, are you downvoting them? If so [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) may delete them if you do that.

Comment: I'm downvoting only very bad question, not all that are not fully fine. But it's just the solution ?

Comment: So you won't downvote them but you think they are not useful. Seems you're not using the site as intended. You already have the tools to solve the problem, you just need to be brave enough to use them.

Comment: I don't use downvote because I'm already sharing feedback that is better than just downvote because people will know what is the issue

Comment: "that is better than just downvote" It is not. Specifically, by just commenting "A lot of them will stay forever somewhere without any way to answer." If you are hesitant to down/close vote because content might improve, consider to vote anyways but *follow* the content so that you can reverse your vote once there is actual improvement.

Comment: And yet nothing happens from your feedback and then you get frustrated so your current course of action isn't working for you is it?

Comment: I mainly ask that it's better to flag or to use share feedback. But I think there is a problem if we should do multiple actions do make it works

Comment: Why is doing multiple things a problem? Posts may have multiple different faults and multiple different actions may be appropriate. Nobody's stopping you doing more than one thing except you.

Comment: Your "share feedback" option is to downvote. The feature exists, you're just not using it.

Comment: I understand. But when use downvote & flag ? Just downvote ?

Comment: The problem is the interface. The "share feedback" should auto-raise a flag/cast a close vote when the comment overlaps with a close reason. It makes no sense to post a comment saying "the question is unclear" but not cast/raise a "needs clarity or details" vote/flag. Now that you know the UI is flawed, you can correct by both raising a flag and using the "share feedback" button.

Comment: I totally agree with Yivi's comment, si I convert my question to a feature request

Comment: @yivi But wee needs more close voteses. Yes, precious.

Comment: @AdrianMole if they are automatic, they can be not count

Comment: @Elikill58 Well, if that "Share Feedback" option were to cast a *free* close vote, then ... fantastic! Or, at least, they could push the post into the Close Votes review queue?

Comment: @AdrianMole what about people that don't have close vote privileges ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automatic actions like close voting/flagging and upvoting are not a good idea. There are likely to be many exceptions when you want to share feedback, but not close vote/flag. Auto-close-voting/auto-flagging when sharing feedback will also make people not want to share feedback as much, meaning the newer users won't get shown their small mistakes as often

If you'd like to close-vote/flag it, just open it in a new tab and do what you need.

Comment: You can flag before share feedback. Also, when you flag for spam there is downvote. And when you share as "Too broad", it's exactly the explaination of "need focus" question. I understand that custom feedback don't create flag, but some choice should do -for me-

Comment: Spam questions are *always* bad questions so that is understandable, but share feedback should not always give an auto-flag